# Excel + Conditional Formatting hardcodes / formulas / lnks

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to conditonally format an entire excel worksheet where all the hard coded cell values are blue, all the links are green, and all the formulas are black?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Excel? xl2013 introduced the [ISFORMULA function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ISFORMULA-function-E4D1355F-7121-4EF2-801E-3839BFD6B1E5). Between that and other native worksheet functions you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for cell value color, just change the font.color after your hard coded value. same for the links. But I don't get what you mean in changing the color of forumla.